# Unable to upload pictures with ng-file-upload to Rails

Tags: angularjs, carrierwave, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory, ng-file-upload

I am using AngularJs with ng-file-upload and Ruby on Rails 4 with CarrierWave.  I have a multistep form with a factory called `CreateEvent` that is used to hold data throughout the form.   Here is the factory:

```
.factory('CreateEvent', function(){
          var formData = {};
          formData.image_collection = [];

          return {
            getFormData:function(){
                     return formData;
            },

            addImage:function(image){
              formData.image_collection.push(image)
            },
            images:function(){
              return formData.image_collection;
            }
          } 
})
```

And here is the controller.  I use only one controller for all views in the form.

```
.controller('ActivityDashboardCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaImagePicker, $ionicPlatform, CreateEvent, Upload) {

  $scope.formData = CreateEvent;

  $scope.saveForm = function(){
        Upload.upload({url: "http://localhost:3000/api/events", data: $scope.formData.getFormData()});
  }
})
```

After going through several pages of the multistep form, The final view allows a user to upload multiple photos. As you can see from the controller, all of the form data is held in `$scope.formData`.

Here is the final view:

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="saveForm()">
    Upload Images
</button>
```

When I click the button, it successfully sends a post request to the server.  However, the server is not properly saving the images.  I know the server works because images are being successfully created through another api.   I'm not sure if the post request contains the actual images or just strings of the images.  Here are the server logs with information about the request:

```
Started POST "/api/events" for ::1 at 2016-04-19 11:19:19 -0400
Processing by Api::EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"image_collection"=>{"0"=>"file:///Users/philipgreenwald/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9B6CA8AC-0A18-4EBB-940E-9ADAE963F26E/data/Containers/Data/Application/37787F7F-CDF0-4F87-A579-5C23D4C154F8/tmp/cdv_photo_055.jpg"}, "category"=>"Special Events", "sub_categories"=>{"Funeral"=>"Funeral"}}
the params are: 

{"image_collection"=>{"0"=>"file:///Users/philipgreenwald/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9B6CA8AC-0A18-4EBB-940E-9ADAE963F26E/data/Containers/Data/Application/37787F7F-CDF0-4F87-A579-5C23D4C154F8/tmp/cdv_photo_055.jpg"}, "category"=>"Special Events", "sub_categories"=>{"Funeral"=>"Funeral"}, "controller"=>"api/events", "action"=>"create"}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "pictures" ("file", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["file", nil], ["created_at", "2016-04-19 15:19:19.530242"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-19 15:19:19.530242"]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but here is the function that adds the images to `formData`:

```
        $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {
            // Loop through acquired images
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log(i);
                console.log(results[i]);
                $scope.formData.addImage(results[i]);
            }
        }
```

I'm pretty sure this is a client-side problem having something to do with the way i call `upload` in the controller.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Is `results[i] instanceof Blob` true? You need to add files to the formData